# Save output and exit code of command to files on windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

I want to run a command and save its *output* **and** its *exit code*, in different files.

Here's what i am doing:

```
cmd.exe /C command 1> %TEMP%\output.log 2> %TEMP%\error.log && echo %ERRORLEVEL% > %TEMP%\status || echo %ERRORLEVEL% > %TEMP%\status
```

If i don't do output redirection (into `%TEMP%\output.log` and/or `%TEMP%\error.log`), then exit code is saved just fine.
However, when i run the line as shown above *more than once* (just get back to previous line in command prompt and rerun it), i get 0 in `%TEMP%\status` regardless of the real exit code.

What am i missing?
Or maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing won't save the exit code, as you're not capturing it. The simplest way is to run the command from inside a batch file. Redirect the output as normal and have the batch file save the ERRORLEVEL value to the second file.

Comment: What do you mean i am not capturing it? Should't %ERRORLEVEL% env contain exit code of last executed command in session?

Comment: Yes, it does but any other operation will change it. In this instance the piping operations will themselves produce exit codes and that's what you will be getting, not the exit code from the command. Doing it in a batch file changes how the system does things.